# Migrate SPNEGO configuration from Wildfly 18 to Wildfly 28

Tags: wildfly, spnego, elytron

I'm using SPNEGO authentication on Wildfly 18 and now I'm migrating to Wildfly 28 and cannot figure out hot to migrate configuration for SPNEGO.

Currently I have this in configuration.xml:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="spnego-server">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="storeKey" value="true"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="spnego-client">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
```

nothing else about spnego is in configuration. It handles application itself and needs just this in config.
How to set this in Wildfly 28 configuration?